# In IDEA, I pushed my project to my GitHub repository, but I found that the account is not mine, seriously it not exist, why?

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I found the name "lemon-mylaptop" is the global user name of git. Normally, it should be my GitHub account, but it isn't.

What is the reason for this?

[image: click to see the picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub resolves the username by email. You should check email preferences of your commits (e.g. with `git log`).

[Further explanation](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally, I found that if the global user.email of Git is equal to GitHub account's email, this page will show my GitHub account, otherwise, the account can't be found.